# sometimes webservice returns 1000 records. how to handle in code?

Tags: java, android, c++

when my Android app makes a web service call, normally 10-300 records are returned, but sometimes, 1000+ records needs to be returned in json file, this can potentially cause memory problems and the app to freeze up... how can i write code to handle such a situation?

Comment: do you need to show all the records at once? if not then you can use pagination kind of stuff. Depending upon the page number we display the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can prevent this memory problems using

```
$top
```

in the parameter, for example:

http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Category(1)/Products?$top=2&$orderby=name

It just response with 2 records, use the number you consider.

Hope it helps to you